# Angular Drag and Drop While Keeping Data In Old Array

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, drag-and-drop

It looks like this question has been asked several times but no answer has been posted yet. Hopefully this time will be the lucky charm.

I am developing an Angular application that has a drag and drop feature that moves items from one array to another array while keeping the original array contents intact. Basically I am trying to make a selector tab that can be dragged to a selection tab but keeps the selector tab intact instead of moving over to the selection tab.

I have included the html and ts code below, this application is currently fully functional with no error codes at this time.

HTML

```
 <div class="cm-content-blocks">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
             <li><a routerLink="/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>
             <li><a [routerLink]="['/ingest-rdbms/']"><i class="fa fa-list mr-1"></i>Choose Data Source</a></li>
             <li class="active" ><i class="fa fa-database"></i>Configure Source</li>

         </ol>
</div>
<div class="row mt-2">
  <div class="col-md-8">
<!-- search box -->
    <!-- <aside class="col-md-4 zeroplimp float-left">
      <div class="searchbarc fifteenpb">
        <input class="search-bar input-field"  type="text"  placeholder="Search by database name"  [(ngModel)]="term">
        <img class="search-bar-icon" src="../../../assets/images/search.svg">
      </div>
    </aside> -->
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">


  

<div>
  <h4 class="innrcaption">Databases:</h4>

  <div
    cdkDropList
    #databaseDropListList="cdkDropList"
    [cdkDropListData]="databaseDropList"
    [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[ingestionDropListList]"
    class="example-list tree_drop"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="databaseDropList" class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">    </div>

      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let database of databaseDropList | filter: term" cdkDrag>
          <span (click)="getDropTables(database,database.databaseName)">{{database.databaseName}}</span>
          <ul *ngIf="showToggle[database.databaseName]">
            <li *ngFor="let table of database.tables; let i=index; " >
              <span
                (click)="getDropColumns(table,database.databaseName+'.'+table.tableName)">{{table.tableName}}</span>
              <ul *ngIf="showToggle[database.databaseName+'.'+table.tableName]">
                <li *ngFor="let column of table.columns " >
                  {{column.columnName}}
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>    
    
    
    <hr/>
    
  </div>
</div>

</div>
<div class="col-md-6">

<div>
  <h4 class="innrcaption">Drag and drop selected databases here:</h4>

  <div
    cdkDropList
    #ingestionDropListList="cdkDropList"
    [cdkDropListData]="ingestionDropList"
    [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[databaseDropListList]"
    class="example-list tree_drop"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div cdkDropList [cdkDropListData]="ingestionDropList" class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">    </div>

    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let database of ingestionDropList; let tableIndex = index" cdkDrag>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <span >{{database.databaseName}}</span>

          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 d-flex flex-row-reverse">
            <!-- <button class="btn btn-light" (click)="toggleTables(database.databaseName); "><i class="{{toggleSortIcon?'fa fa-angle-down':'fa fa-angle-up'}}" ></i></button> -->
            <button class="btn btn-light " (click)="refreshTables(database,database.databaseName,tableIndex); "><i class="fa fa-undo" ></i></button> 
            <button class="btn btn-light mr-2" (click)="getTables(database, database.databaseName,tableIndex);toggleTableList[tableIndex]= !toggleTableList[tableIndex] "><i class="{{toggleTableList[tableIndex]?'fa fa-angle-up':'fa fa-angle-down'}}" ></i></button>

          </div>
        </div>
        <ul *ngIf="showToggle[database.databaseName]">
          <li *ngFor="let table of database.tables; let columnIndex =index;" >
            <div class="row  mt-2">
              <div class="col-md-8">
                <span (click)="getDropColumns(table,database.databaseName+'.'+table.tableName)">{{table.tableName}}</span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4 d-flex flex-row-reverse">
                <button class="btn btn-light" (click)="deleteTable(database.tables,table)"><i class="fa fa-trash" ></i></button>
                  <button class="btn btn-light mr-2" (click)="refreshColumns(table,database.databaseName+'.'+table.tableName,columnIndex); "><i class="fa fa-undo" ></i></button> 
                <button class="btn btn-light mr-2" (click)="getColumns(table,database.databaseName+'.'+table.tableName,columnIndex,table.tableName);toggleColumnIcon[columnIndex]= !toggleColumnIcon[columnIndex]"><i class="{{toggleColumnIcon[columnIndex]?'fa fa-angle-up':'fa fa-angle-down'}}" ></i></button>

              </div>
            </div>
            
            <ul *ngIf="showToggle[database.databaseName+'.'+table.tableName]">
              <li *ngFor="let column of table.columns; let i =index;" >
                <div class="row mt-2">
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                    <span (click)="getDropColumns(table,database.databaseName+'.'+table.tableName)">{{column.columnName}}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4 d-flex flex-row-reverse">
                    <button class="btn btn-light" (click)="deleteColumn(table,column);"><i class="fa fa-trash" ></i></button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>    
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<button class="tertiary-active fr float-right" (click)="carryState()">Next</button>
```

TS

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray, transferArrayItem } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import { CatalogService } from "../../../services/api/catalogService/catalog.service"
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, NavigationExtras } from '@angular/router';
import { analyzeAndValidateNgModules } from '@angular/compiler';
import { JsonpClientBackend } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MatSnackBar, MatSnackBarConfig, MatSnackBarHorizontalPosition, MatSnackBarVerticalPosition, } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';


declare var $: any;

interface DatabaseNode {
  databaseName: string;
  id?: string;
  dataType?: string;
  primaryKey?: boolean;
  tables?: TableNode[];
}

interface TableNode {
  tableName: string;
  id?: string;
  dataType?: string;
  primaryKey?: boolean;
  columns?: columnNode[];
}

interface columnNode {
  columnName: string;
  id?: string;
  dataType?: string;
  primaryKey?: boolean;
}


interface toggle {
  name: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-configure-ingestion',
  templateUrl: './configure-ingestion.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./configure-ingestion.component.scss']
})
export class ConfigureIngestionComponent implements OnInit {

  //drag and drop lists
  public databaseDropList: DatabaseNode[] = [];
  ingestionDropList: DatabaseNode[] = [];

  //database object
  public databaseResponse: any;
  finalDatabaseObject: DatabaseNode[]
  //source id
  id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'];


  //term for search input
  term: string;

  //toggle attribute
  showToggle: any = [];

  toggleColumnList: any = [];
  refreshColumnList: any = [];
  toggleColumnIcon: any = []
  stringArray: any = []



  toggleTableList: any = []
  refreshTableList: any = []


  //toggle buttons
  toggleSortIcon = true;
  toggleLoadIcon = true;
  // toggleTables = true;

  //snackbar
  horizontalPosition: MatSnackBarHorizontalPosition = 'start';
  verticalPosition: MatSnackBarVerticalPosition = 'bottom';




  constructor(private service: CatalogService, public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef, public router: Router, private snackBar: MatSnackBar
  ) { }


  //Drag side 

  //retrieve database 

  //retrieve tables

  getDropTables(database: any, toggleTables: string) {



    let tables: any = [];


    this.showToggle[toggleTables] = !this.showToggle[toggleTables]


    this.service.getCatalog("tables/" + database.id).toPromise()
      .then(response => {
        let data: any;
        data = response;
        for (let table of data.tables) {
          tables.push({ tableName: table.tableName, id: table.tableId })
        }
        database.tables = tables;
        if (database.tables.length > 0) {
        } else {
          this.openSnackBar("No tables in database ", "❗")
        }
        console.log(database.tables.length)

      });


  }


  //retrieve columns 

  getDropColumns(table: any, toggleColumns: string) {
    let columns: any = [];

    this.showToggle[toggleColumns] = !this.showToggle[toggleColumns]

    this.service.getCatalog("columns/" + table.id).toPromise()
      .then(response => {
        let data: any;
        console.log(response)
        data = response;
        for (let column of data.columns) {
          columns.push({ columnName: column.columnName, dataType: column.dataType, primaryKey: column.primaryKey })
        }
        table.columns = columns;
      });


  }

  //Drop side

  //retrieve database 
  getAllDatabases() {
    this.service.postCatalog(this.id).toPromise()
      .then(response => {
        let data: any;
        data = response;
        let databaseArray = []

        this.databaseResponse = data.databases
        for (let row of this.databaseResponse) {


          databaseArray.push({ databaseName: row.databaseName, id: row.databaseId })
        }
        this.databaseDropList = databaseArray
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()
      }
      )
  }




  //retrieve tables

  getTables(database: any, toggleTables: string, tableIndex: number) {
    let tables: any = [];

    console.log(database)
    if (this.toggleTableList[tableIndex] == undefined) {
      this.service.getCatalog("tables/" + database.id).toPromise()
        .then(response => {
          let data: any;
          data = response;
          for (let table of data.tables) {
            tables.push({ tableName: table.tableName, id: table.tableId })
          }
          database.tables = tables;

        });



      this.toggleTableList[tableIndex] = true;
    }


    this.showToggle[toggleTables] = !this.showToggle[toggleTables]


  }

  //refresh columns
  refreshTables(database: any, toggleTables: string, tableIndex: number) {
    let tables: any = [];

    this.service.getCatalog("tables/" + database.id).toPromise()
      .then(response => {
        let data: any;
        data = response;
        for (let table of data.tables) {
          tables.push({ tableName: table.tableName, id: table.tableId })
        }
        database.tables = tables;

      })

  }


  //retrieve columns 

  getColumns(table: any, toggleColumns: string, index: number, name: string) {
    let columns: any = [];


    if (this.toggleColumnList[index] == undefined) {

      this.service.getCatalog("columns/" + table.id).toPromise()
        .then(response => {
          let data: any;
          data = response;
          for (let column of data.columns) {
            columns.push({ columnName: column.columnName, dataType: column.dataType, primaryKey: column.primaryKey })
          }
          table.columns = columns;
        });



      this.toggleColumnList[index] = false;

    }


    this.showToggle[toggleColumns] = !this.showToggle[toggleColumns]


  }

  countInArray(array: [], frequency: number) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i] === frequency) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    return count;
  }

  //refresh columns
  refreshColumns(table: any, toggleColumns: string, index: number) {
    let columns: any = [];


    this.service.getCatalog("columns/" + table.id).toPromise()
      .then(response => {
        let data: any;
        console.log(response)
        data = response;
        for (let column of data.columns) {
          columns.push({ columnName: column.columnName, dataType: column.dataType, primaryKey: column.primaryKey })
        }
        table.columns = columns;
      });
  }


  //toggle feature
  changeToggle(name: string) {
    this.showToggle[name] = !this.showToggle[name]


  }

  //snackbar
  openSnackBar(status: string, statusLogo: string) {
    this.snackBar.open(status, statusLogo, {
      duration: 1000,
      horizontalPosition: this.horizontalPosition,
      verticalPosition: this.verticalPosition,
      panelClass: ['tertiary-active']

    });
  }





  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAllDatabases();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    $(document).ready(function () {
      var contenth = $(window).height() - 110;
      var sidebarh = $(window).height() - 111;
      $(".pagec").css("height", contenth);
      $(".sidebar-wrapper").css("height", sidebarh);

      /* tree view */
      var tree_height = $(window).height() - 240;
      $(".tree_drop").css("height", tree_height);
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
      /* tree view */
      var tree_height = $(window).height() - 240;
      $(".tree_drop").css("height", tree_height);
    })
  }

  //delete table from droplist
  deleteTable(parent: any, child: any) {
    parent.splice(parent.indexOf(child), 1)
    console.log("ingestion")
    console.log(this.ingestionDropList)
  }



  //delete column from droplist
  deleteColumn(parent: any, child: any) {
    parent.columns.splice(parent.columns.indexOf(child), 1)
    console.log("ingestion")
    console.log(this.ingestionDropList)
    // this.router.navigateByUrl(`/ingest-rdbms/${this.id}`);

  }


  //carry state over to next page
  carryState() {
    this.router.navigate([`advancedConfiguration/${this.id}/`], { queryParams: { data: JSON.stringify(this.ingestionDropList) } });

  }


  //drag and drop 
  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<DatabaseNode[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex);
      this.finalDatabaseObject = this.databaseDropList
      console.log("ingestion")
      console.log(this.ingestionDropList)
      //finished list: this.ingestions
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer myself, but for anyone seeking a solution to this all I had to do was change transferItemInArray to CopyArrayItem

```
//drag and drop 
  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<DatabaseNode[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      copyArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex);
      this.finalDatabaseObject = this.databaseDropList
      console.log("ingestion")
      console.log(this.ingestionDropList)
      //finished list: this.ingestions
    }
  }
```